# Implicit join in lucene

Tags: join, lucene

Is it possible to do something like the following in lucene?  If not, can you give any suggestions for how to get around this limitation?

```
SELECT
start.dt AS eventstarttime,
last.dt AS eventfinishtime
WHERE
start.evt:"Started" AND last.evt:"Ended" AND start.evtgrpid = last.evtgrpid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not give enough information to fully answer it. This SQL is not even valid - where is the `FROM` clause (for a start)?

Suggestion 1: run two queries ("Started" and "Ended") separately and merge the results based on `evtgrpid`.

Suggestion 2: run one query (e.g. "Started") and filter the results based on "Ended" criteria.

Suggestion 3: do not use Lucene for what databases are built for. Really. Often database logic does not even apply to Lucene (e.g. what if stopwords are used when indexing?).

Comment: There is no FROM clause in Lucene query syntax as far as I can tell.  Suggestion 1 is not an option because I'm writing a query for a jasper report - the results from the query are automatically parsed into a report.  Suggestion 2 doesn't work for the same reason.  Suggestion 3 is an invalid premise - I have to use Lucene for this particular report.

Comment: You gave us SQL query to be converted into a Lucene query. As a SQL query, it is invalid. As a Lucene query, it is invalid either - Lucene has no `SELECT` nor `WHERE`, etc.